# Phabricator: How to disable autocomplete on login forms?

Tags: phabricator, forms, http-post

Just installed 'Phabricator' in our organization and getting used to it. However, our IT objects to the autocomplete feature on the login form.

Can this be disabled in a humane way? (ie. without breaking anything else)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the code of Phabricator, https://secure.phabricator.com/D10253 can serve as a guide.

Understand that simply setting autocomplete=off will not fix the issue with some browsers, who ignore the developers wishes (like Chrome and Firefox).

See https://secure.phabricator.com/T5579 for discussion.

Comment: Thanks @chad-little. I will give it a try tomorrow. Understood that the issue/solution resides more in the browser than the server, but this whole exercise is just to respond to our IT teams' objections.

Comment: Turns out my installation already has this patch. How do I use/enable this?

Comment: Also (reading the commit log) looks like this fix applies to non-login forms only. `commit bcdadf594 Add autocomplete=off to all non-login password forms`

Comment: Found it, after some digging. Posting as a new answer just for formatting, otherwise I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
diff --git a/src/applications/auth/provider/PhabricatorPasswordAuthProvider.php b/src/applications/auth/provider/PhabricatorPasswordAuthProvider.php
index 68dbf1e..43d5932 100644
--- a/src/applications/auth/provider/PhabricatorPasswordAuthProvider.php
+++ b/src/applications/auth/provider/PhabricatorPasswordAuthProvider.php
@@ -230,11 +230,13 @@ final class PhabricatorPasswordAuthProvider extends PhabricatorAuthProvider {
       ->setLabel(pht('Username or Email'))
       ->setName('username')
       ->setValue($v_user)
+      ->setDisableAutocomplete(true)
       ->setError($e_user))
   ->appendChild(
     id(new AphrontFormPasswordControl())
       ->setLabel(pht('Password'))
       ->setName('password')
+   ->setDisableAutocomplete(true)
    ->setError($e_pass));

if ($require_captcha) {
```

(However, I will still accept @chad-little 's answer)